# Install Ubuntu Linux Desktop 15.x on Pre-installed Windows 8.1 laptop and have dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I looked at various questions all over the internet. Infact i did the same almost 6 months back on my HP Desktop but i did so much hit and trial that i have forgotten what to do this time?
Do i need to do any or all of them or what specifically?
Disable Secure Boot in BIOS?
Disable quick start within Windows 8.1?
Disable UEFI Boot and enable legacy boot?

What all i need to do?
On top of it, i have no idea what needs to be done exactly? There are so many blogs and stuff on internet forums with a very confusing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detailed guide.[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) 
Download the iso(you can only use the 64bit one with UEFI.), make sure that the download is not corrupted by getting it's checksum and comparing it with the one provided on the download site. You can do this on Windows8.1 by opening Powershell cd-ing to the directory of the iso and running
`Get-FileHash -Algorithm sha256/md5/etc .\filenamegoeshere.iso`(It's slow)
then burn it to a clean USB. (I used `imageusb` just 2 days ago, since `Unetbootin` didn't work for me). 
Once you did this follow the guide above.

Comment: where is the 64 bit with UEFI???, if you go there: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop - the only one which is available is 64 bit but NOT 64 bit with UEFI

Comment: I meant the 32bit one does not work with UEFI, the 64bit one does.

Comment: Able to resolve this issue now.

Comment: Finally i am able to resolve this issue. There is nothing called UEFI 64 bit image for Ubuntu Desktop 15.x. It's just called plain 64 bit Ubuntu desktop ISO. Download it from here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
and then follow everything that is being mentioned out here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick